# std::list.erase() seems to be rearranging the elements of the list

Tags: c++, list, erase

Consider the following function

```
void removeOdd(list<int>& li)
{
    for(list<int>::iterator it=li.begin(); it!=li.end(); it++)
    {
        if((*it)%2) it = li.erase(it);
    }
}
```

From my understanding of lists, where the return value is an "iterator pointing to the element that followed the last element erased by the function call",

[std::list.erase() documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8uD5.png)

the `removeOdd()` function should ignore the element after the element erased and carry on through the list.

However, when linked into this test script

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

void test()
{
    int a[9] = { 5, 2, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1 };
    list<int> x(a, a+9);  // construct x from the array
    assert(x.size() == 9 && x.front() == 5 && x.back() == 1);
    removeOdd(x);
    assert(x.size() == 4);
    vector<int> v(x.begin(), x.end());  // construct v from x
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    int expect[4] = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        assert(v[k] == expect[k]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    test();
    cout << "Passed" << endl;
}
```

it passes. Moreover, modifying removeOdd() to

```
void removeOdd(list<int>& li)
{
    for(list<int>::iterator it=li.begin(); it!=li.end(); it++)
    {
        if((*it)%2){
            cout << *it << " ";
            it = li.erase(it);
            cout << *it << endl;
        } 
        else cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

and running the entire script on my WSL instance (compiling with g++), the following output is produced:

```
5 2
8
9 6
7 3
4
1 5
2
8
6
3 4
Passed
```

Am I missing something or is the list iterator looping back into the list?

I tried to read documentation online about `std::list.erase()` and random access iterators, but still could not understand the behavior described above.

Comment: You only want to `it++` when you do not erase from the list.  Right now you are always doing `it++` and will skip items in the list.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think OP understands that and that's why he finds it strange that the test appears to pass. Since items are skipped in the list, the test should not pass.

Comment: *still could not understand the behavior described above* Not much to be understood, and any understanding you do reach is generally not going to be portable. The behaviour of Undefined Behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `removeOdd()`, you are incrementing `it` on every loop iteration, even when you remove an item, which will cause you to skip the next item, or even increment out of bounds. You need to increment `it` only for items that you *don't* remove, eg:

```
void removeOdd(list<int>& li)
{
    for(list<int>::iterator it = li.begin(); it != li.end(); )
    {
        if (*it % 2)
            it = li.erase(it);
        else
            ++it:
    }
}
```

A better option is to use [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with [`list::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) instead of using a manual loop, eg:

```
void removeOdd(list<int>& li)
{
    li.erase(
        remove_if(li.begin(), li.end(),
                  [](int i){ return (i % 2) != 0; }
        ),
        li.end()
    );
}
```

In C++20 and later, you can use [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase2) instead, eg:

```
void removeOdd(list<int>& li)
{
    erase_if(li,
        [](int i){ return (i % 2) != 0; }
    );
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your `test()` example, your original code does not actually work:

- it checks and removes 5 from the list
- it skips checking 2, leaving it in the list!
- it checks and keeps 8 in the list
- it checks and removes 9 from the list
- it skips checking 6, leaving it in the list!
- it checks and removes 7 from the list
- it skips checking 3, leaving it in the list!
- it checks and keeps 4 in the list
- it checks and removes 1 from the list
- IT SHOULD STOP HERE, BUT IT DOESN'T!!!!
- it skips checking 5, leaving it in the list!
- it checks and keeps 2 in the list
- it checks and keeps 8 in the list
- it checks and keeps 6 in the list
- it checks and removes 3 from the list
- it skips checking 4, leaving it in the list!

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/BkMW80)

You removed the last item from the list, and then incremented `it` (which is now equal to the `end` iterator), thus going out of bounds of the list because `it != li.end()` is no longer valid, and thus your code exhibits **undefined behavior**.

So, simply by a fluke of UB, you ended up with a result of `[2,8,6,4]` (before sorting). You *would have* gotten `[2,8,6,3,4]` instead if the UB was not present.

Fixing `removeOdd()` as I described above solves the UB problem, and gives the expected result:

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/6AQDb6)

Comment: This is indeed the issue with the code and the fix for it, but this is not what OP is asking. OP is asking why the code appears to work while it should not.